# Usage of $\mathbf{Z}$ vs. $\Bbb Z$ in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, notation

This is just a notational question but it seems that in texts on Number Theory, boldface letters are used instead of blackboard bold (e.g. $\mathbf{Q}$ vs. $\Bbb Q$). Is there any specific reason for this or is it just notational convention?

Comment: the story I got is that the blackboard letters happened because people writing on blackboards usually do not fill in the bold letters; letters with multiple lines are easier. Bold letters were preferred in printing and still are, I guess. Not by everyone.

Comment: I have seen plenty of number theory books which use the blackboard bold letters. I suspect it comes down to the preferences of the author and/or publisher.

Comment: @WillJagy I'm aware of this story and it makes sense, but I only ever see things like $\mathbf{Q}$ in number theory texts

Comment: Right. It is different now, authors have been using Tex and Latex since, say, 1980. I use $\mathbb Z$ myself. So this issue varies by decade, say, by publisher  and perhaps by country.

Comment: Alright, got curious. the Latex installed on my computer did not come with $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Z.$  So, the one occurrence I can find in my article in a 2013 book is $\bf Z$

Comment: I can't say why, but I've generally gotten the impression that the use of bold (instead of blackboard bold) for sets of numbers is much more common among French writers.